# Unable to find the element - org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, selenium, nosuchelementexception

I have indicated the correct name but why is the input element still not found?

WARNING: Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 107, so returning the closest version found: 106
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#"firstname""}
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [9d77f, findElement {using=name, value="firstname"}]

html

```
<input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" value="" title="First Name" class="input-text required-entry" data-validate="{required:true}" autocomplete="off" aria-required="true">
```

```
.......
sel.Fields("textbox", "firstname");

}

public boolean Fields(String field, String name) {
    boolean f;
     if (field.equals("textbox")){
            return f= driver.findElement(By.name('"'+ name +'"')).isDisplayed();
           
     }

     return false;

        }
```

Can anyone help me on this as I have use findElement By.name

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "I have use findElement By.name" Why are you trying to find a locator By.name if you have an ID element that is unique?